# How to resize and float right a background image using css?

Tags: html, css

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and I have a requirement to add the background image to the top banner which I did.

What I can't figure out how to do is how to shift it all the way to the right and make it smaller in length so that it only takes up half of the screen width.

Any idea how to do that?  So far I have this css for the overall banner div:

```
.banner 
{
    width:60em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemiotoprightimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: right-align
}
```

but I don't know how to make the background image align right and rescale to be 50% of the entire width of the div.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to include scaling in your CSS. If the image needs to be a particular size, make it that size.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top` and `center` for aligning backgrounds. Also percentages.

```
background: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemiotoprightimage.png') right no-repeat;
```

However, you cannot resize the images using CSS2 but in CSS3.

```
background-size: <width> <height>;
```

More usage:

```
background: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemiotoprightimage.png') top right no-repeat;
```

To align bottom and centered:

```
background: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemiotoprightimage.png') bottom center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Unless you use [CSS3's `background-size` property](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/), which has [decent browser support](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts).

Comment: Updated my post to that CSS2 doesn't support resizing background images, but in CSS3 it's possible. Cheers! *learned something new today*

Comment: Thanks what I still don't understand is what is causing the very right little bit of the banner to be solid gray and the background image not extending there.  Would you know why that is happening?

Answer (score 10):

Use `background-position: right;` and `background-size: [width] [height]` (replace values where needed).